# What the statement inside the parentheses means

Tags: c++

Dont understand what the expression in the while statement means below. Please someone explain

```
while(trans->link){
    trans = trans->link;
}
```

Comment: Given the context of the compound statement `while(trans->link)` is the equivalent to `while(trans->link != nullptr)`. Pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple linked-list traversal to find the last element of the list.  That is, while `trans->link` is non-zero (i.e., not `NULL` - past the end of the list), it will move one step farther down the list: `trans = trans->link`.

Answer (score 0):

`->` is the class member accessor for a pointer.  Presumably `trans` is a pointer and `trans->link` is a pointer of the same type.  The above code says "while `trans->link` is not zero, assign `trans` to be `trans->link`, ultimately moving to the end of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a structure:

```
struct Element 
{
    int value;
    Element *next;
};
```

Linked list consists of nodes that are type `Element` , and it has a pointer to the head of linked list(first node). The `next` pointer of the last element of a list points to `nullptr`(if not familiar with linked lists read [More Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)).

If you wish to traverse the whole list you need to have a `Element *temp` pointer that will point to the `head` (because we don't want to lose our head of the list). And then, after visiting one node, we have to move `temp` to the next element of the node we are currently pointing to(`temp=temp->next`).

We will stop the traversal until `temp` reaches `nullptr`. That's when the while loop will break.

In your case

`link=next`

`trans=temp`

Hope it helps.